# Java If Else Statement with random value from 1 to 7 and 1 to 6

Tags: java

I'm currently working on a program which stimulates a simple casino machine. If the user gets two matching numbers, from the three included wheels,  ranging from one through seven they win $1. I need to include an if else statement where the user will gain $2 if they match three numbers ranging from one through six.

```
wheelone = generator.nextInt(7) + 1;
wheeltwo = generator.nextInt(7) + 1;
wheelthree = generator.nextInt(7) + 1;
```

Here's a portion of my current if else statement where the three wheels need to be equal but only range from one through six.

```
if (wheelone == wheeltwo && wheelone == wheelthree && wheeltwo == wheelthree)
            {
                bank = bank + 2; 
                System.out.println("Won: 2 dollars");
            }
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: If `w1 == w2` AND `w1 == w3` then you already know `w2 == w3`, so the last check is redundant. Removing redundant code makes the real issues easier to spot. Having said that, I have no idea what your real issue is...

Comment: Can they win $3 if both things are true?

Comment: The if statement I have written grants the user $2 if they match three numbers from one to seven. I'm unsure how to make it so they would receive $2 only if they match three numbers ranging from one to six, because if they matched three sevens they would receive jackpot, a $10 prize.